# sqlite adding days to a date

Tags: ios, datetime, sqlite

I'm trying to write an sqlite statement which returns a date from the table with a certain number of days added from another column. The date is stored as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` and the number of days just as an integer.

I've got

```
SELECT strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' , 
strftime('%s',transactions.date)+repeattransactions.interval*24*60*60) 
FROM transactions,repeattransactions
```

but this is adding wierd amounts to the years and all sorts. Wonder if I could get some help adding the days and outputting it in the same format?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.7 2011-06-23 19:49:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> create table t (tdate, tinterval);
sqlite> insert into t values ('2011-09-08 11:11:11', 5);
sqlite> select datetime(t.tdate,'+'||t.tinterval||' days') from t;
2011-09-13 11:11:11
```

See [SQLite3 Date & Time Functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

Comment: You're welome; the || "double pipe" is SQL string concatenation. I wasn't certain using it with a column name would work in the modifier argument to datetime, but it seems to do just what you'd expect.