# How to sum dates with foreign keys

Tags: sqlite, datetime

I can't find a way to sum this date i have in a Table(Data_Cadastro) to a number of days in other table

```
(SELECT Validade from Documento WHERE Documento_Colaborador.ID_Documento = Documento.ID_Documento)
```

I've managed to sum fixed days with

```
SELECT Data_Cadastro , strftime('%d/%m/%Y',Data_Cadastro, '5 days') from Documento_Colaborador
```

but i can't find a way of doing it with a variable value

This is the code i got so far

```
SELECT Data_Cadastro , strftime('%d/%m/%Y',Data_Cadastro, +(SELECT Validade from Documento WHERE Documento_Colaborador.ID_Documento = Documento.ID_Documento)) from Documento_Colaborador
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transform your date to seconds since 1970 ("unixepoch") and add the number of seconds in 5 days, then convert it back to date:

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y',
datetime(strftime('%s', '2019-01-12') + 5 * 24 * 3600, 'unixepoch'));

>>> 17/01/2019
```

(change the date and "5" to your query and add your tables).

You can also build a string "5 days" like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7351572/6401403):

```
select strftime('%d/%m/%Y', datetime('2019-01-12', '+'||5||' days'));

>>> 17/01/2019
```

(also change the date and "5" to your query).